# RetainCount Memory not free'ed

Tags: cocoa, memory-management

I am stuck with the Cocoa Memory Managagment.

```
- (IBAction) createPush:(UIButton *)sender {
    [create setEnabled:NO];
    [release setEnabled:YES];

    aLocation = [[Location alloc] init];

    // Put some Example Stuff in the Class
    aLocation.title = @"Apartment";
    aLocation.street = @"Examplestreet 23";
    aLocation.zip = @"12345";
    aLocation.city = @"Exampletown";
    aLocation.http = @"http://google.com";
    aLocation.info = @"First Info Text";
    aLocation.info2 = @"Second Info Text, not short as the first one";
    aLocation.logoPath = @"http://google.de/nopic.jpg";

    [aLocation.pictures addObject:@"http://google.de/nopic.jpg"];
    [aLocation.pictures addObject:@"http://google.de/nopic.jpg"];
}

 - (IBAction) releasePush:(UIButton *)sender {
     [release setEnabled:NO];
     [create setEnabled:YES];

     [aLocation release];
     aLocation = nil;
}
```

This Code works fine if I set or get Variables, but when I call the 'last' release (so the retain count is 0) it dealloc Method of aLocation gets called, but in Instruments Allocations you see that no memory is given back.

Here the Sources of Location:

http://homes.dnsalias.com/sof/Location.m
same Link with a '.h' instead of '.m' for the Header file (sorry its because of the Spaming Rule).

And the whole Project: http://homes.dnsalias.com/sof/Location.zip

Thanks for any help, where is my failure? Dennis

Comment: Is this all of the code that does anything with `aLocation`? It doesn't get put into an array, for example?

Comment: yes this is all!If you want to take a closer look feel fre to download the sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This Code works fine if I set or get
>   Variables, but when I call the 'last'
>   release (so the retain count is 0) it
>   dealloc Method of aLocation gets
>   called, but in Instruments Allocations
>   you see that no memory is given back.

What do you mean by "no memory is given back"?

Though oddly named, the memory management of `aLocation` is correct is the above code (assuming you have released it in `dealloc` as well).

---

> Why doesn't memory use decrease when a single object is released?

(Paraphrased)

It is likely that your object is relatively tiny and, thus, that single deallocation falls below the ~20K or so needed to show up in Instruments.

If your app is crashing due to memory use issues, looking to a single deallocation is the wrong place to start.  The first thing to do is to answer why your app is accreting memory and what is responsible for that growth.

Configure the Allocations instrument to only track live allocations.  Then sort by total memory use.  That'll show you what type of allocation is consuming the most memory.  Start by reducing that.

[Heapshot analysis](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) can be very effective in these situations.

Comment: Thank you for that great Link. I didnt know about that before, i think this should be helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Additional Infos here because of maximum number of links and I have'nt the opportunity to post images...

> What do you mean by "no memory is given back"?

I will show you the Instruments run, then it should be clear.
[Screenshots from Instruments run](http://gallery.me.com/dennis.stritzke#100029)

If want more Detail klick [here](http://homes.dnsalias.com/sof/locationPost.trace.zip) for Instruments Run.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just fine. You are mistaken the output from Instruments. There is no Location object leaking.

For leaks, use the "Leaks" instrument. It won't fire. :-)

Comment: Ok that sounds nice. But why dont decrease the Memory Usage when i am releasing the aLocation Object. Thats not clear to me. The Problem is that this Class is part of a bigger project and if you use the App the Memory Usage is that big that the App chrashes.